# HAProxy overload protection

Tags: linux, configuration, haproxy

using the HAProxy, would it be possible to configure an overload protection, to limit the amount of requests sent to the backing http server(s) to a given rate (z.B 100 Request per second ). If the threshold is exceeded requests should be answered with a default response.
I am interested in requests per second not connections per second as a connection can have many requests.

And yes to improve the servers is not an option here. If yes a configuration example to achieve that would be excellent.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it's not possible with HAproxy. It does have a session limiting feature, but that's not what you are looking for.

Comment: If you use httpclose or forceclose it would be less efficient but limit to one request per session, yes?  Then you could limit sessions per second.